# Fetching credentials in an AWS Batch job

Tags: rust, aws-batch, aws-credentials

So we are running an AWS Batch job on ECS/Fargate and want to access some AWS service.

Where do I get the credentials (`SecretAccessKey` etc) from, that is the credentials for the assigned Job Role?
Places already checked:

- $HOME/.aws: Does not exist
- Env Vars: Not there
- Env Var `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`: Nope

Using AWS CLI **does** work (magically, as it walks the [credential chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/standardized-credentials.html#credentialProviderChain)), but we do not want to ship AWS CLI nor some AWS SDK.

If we have to `sts_client.assume_role()`, how to do that without an AWS SDK (yes, we are using Rust)?

## Update

When running CLI with `aws configure --debug export-credentials` in the Batch job, we see that the credential gets successfully resolved <s>by the `botocore.credentials.SSOProvider`</s> by calling the endpoint `http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/UUID`. Still a mistery which credential provider does resolve, and where the UUID is sourced from.

Comment: check out the credential endpoint here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html, you might be able to use it directly using something like reqwest. But, may I ask, if you are doing anything with AWS, why not use the AWS rust SDK for it?

Comment: The linked doc referes to the env var `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`, which we do not see in our containers. There is the env var `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI`, which seems to point to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3-fargate-response.html. i.e. no credentials.

Comment: We hesitate to use AWS rust SDK for this seemingly  simple task because compile times go up.

Comment: In a previous `Job Definition` we did not set the `Job/Task Role`. So the container agent could not set `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`. After setting a `Job/Task Role` everything works fine.